# Issue with a loop which checks members in a Discord server

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm pretty new to Python so this is very confusing to me. I'm trying to check all members in a list, where for every member it checks whether it is person A/person B or neither, and then does a certain thing based on whether it is that person or not. For some reason, when the first person checked is the same as the person it checks for, it says that all the following people are that person too.
The code is used to get rid of all members in a discord server except a few (for resetting after a minigame).

```
async def serverreset(ctx):
for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
    print(member)
    if member == "person1#1234" or "person2#2345":
        print(f"Unable to ban {member.display_name}")
    else:
        await member.ban(reason="Reset", delete_message_days=7)
        print(f"Banned {member.display_name}")
```

Result of running the program:

```
person1#1234
Unable to ban person1
person2#2345
Unable to ban person2
accountthatshouldbebanned#5678
Unable to ban accountthatshouldbebanned
```

Comment: Try `if member == "person1#1234" or member == "person2#2345":`

Comment: It's a bad idea to check people against their name/discriminator, you should use the ID (`member.id`). Also as Benjin said, `or` is a low priority operation, try `if member not in ('person1#1234', 'person2#2345')`

Comment: When using `if member not in ('person1#1234', 'person2#2345'):` with the ban command correctly indented on the next line it still tries banning these 2 users. Anything I might be doing wrong? EDIT: just after I posted this Diggy posted his reply, and it fixed my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening there is the string representation (i.e. when being printed or put into a string) of a member object is the user's name + discriminator. But when you're using the member object in a statement, it doesn't convert it to a string.

There are a couple ways you can go about it:

```py
if str(member) in ["person1#1234", "person2#2345"]:
    print(f"Unable to ban {member.display_name}")
else:
    # other code
```

And that would be checking the member as a string. The alternative would be doing it via ID (which is more "failsafe", as IDs never change, but users are able to change their name and discriminator).

```py
if member.id in [112233445566778899, 223344556677889900]:
    print(f"Unable to ban {member.display_name}")
else:
    # other code
```

Another thing to note is that when a bot edits roles, attempts to change a username, or kick/ban someone and that person has higher priveleges than the bot (i.e. the server owner), then it'll throw a `Forbidden` error, as it isn't high enough in the hierarchy to perform the action.

One last thing is in your if statement, you're checking `member == "person#1234" or "person2#2345"`, which in plain english makes perfect sense. However, when the interpreter evaluates statements, it does them separately:

- `if member == "person1#1234"`
- OR
- `if "person2#2345"`

Due to that second part, it will always evaluate to being `True`, and will only ever be `False` if the object is `None`, but because a string isn't `None`, it'll be `True`.

Hoping that made some sense.

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.ban()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.ban)
- [`Member.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.id)
- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) - Check out the `str(x)` to see what it returns when converted to a str
- [Python conditional statements](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was indeed the statement always being true, really appreciate the help!

Comment: No worries, they're always a bit finnicky at the start, but after a couple times you'll be a natural! Good luck with the bot :^)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `member == "person1#1234" or "person2#2345"`
is actually resolved as `( member == "person1#1234") or ("person2#2345)` which will always evaluate to `True`.

You need to use 
`member == "person1#1234" or member == "person2#2345"`.

You can also use
`member in ("person1#1234", "person2#2345")`